dbx: warning: 'main' has no debugger info -- will trigger on first instruction with the -g option added
I am getting this error message. I have already added the -g option.
dbx: warning: 'main' has no debugger info -- will trigger on first instruction
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=d-dbx-command
The ObjectFile parameter is an object (executable) file produced by a compiler. Use the -g (generate symbol table) flag when compiling your program to produce the information the dbx command needs.
Note: The -g flag of the cc command must be used when the object file is compiled. If the -g flag is not used or if symbol references are removed from the xcoff file with the strip command, the symbolic capabilities of the dbx command are limited. In addition, do not use the -O compiler option to optimize an executable that you plan to debug with dbx. Optimization rearranges the code and compromises the debug data, further limiting the value of debugging the executable program with the dbx command.
Using a makefile with the -g option.
DEBUG=-g

Then using the makefile.
make -f program.mak; ./program;

Running it from the command line.
cc  -g program.o  program.c
./program


You have already added the -g option to what? Show every step of compilation, linking, and execution, so we can figure out why your main has no debugger info.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk edited with more information.

Instead of cc -g program.o program.c try this: cc -g -o program program.c

@LorinczyZsigmond neither way would work until I deleted the program.o file or did a make -f makefile.mak clean.

I cannot explain right here what compilation and linkage is, and when these two can be performed in one step; the important bit is that -g is required in both steps.

First check this tutorial. It has some great info.
https://www.oracle.com/solaris/technologies/dbxerr.html
The most likely answer to this is yes you have added the -g option but you have not actually recompiled your program properly. Just recompiling your program is not good enough. You need to do one of two options to delete your program.o file or if you use a makefile do make -f makefile.mak clean. When you do this correctly you should see a similar message to this. Notice how this time it does have the -g option.
cc  -g -I./ -I../inc -Iusr/local/include -Iusr/local/include/ncursesw -I/export/customer/dstn/test/inc -I/opt/oracle/oracle_19.0.0.0/precomp/public -I/opt/oracle/oracle_19.0.0.0/rdbms/public -I/opt/oracle/oracle_19.0.0.0/rdbms/demo -I/opt/oracle/oracle_19.0.0.0/plsql/public -D__sparc -D_STRICT_STDC -features=no%conststrings -xCC -c -o ../uobj/program.o  program.c

